# Convert arrays to different format php

Tags: php, arrays

Is there is simple and quick way to convert php array from

```
 $actions =  Array ( [visits-visit] => Array ( 
                                  [0] => index 
                                  [1] => edit 
                                  [2] => add 
                                  [3] => delete 
                                  [4] => search 
                                ) 
       )
```

to

```
Array ( [visits-visit] => Array ( index ,edit ,add ,delete, search ) )
```

I have an array in the first format, and need to add it as this

```
 $this->allow($_userRole, 'module-contr', array( index ,edit ,add ,delete, search));
```

when I make like this

```
$this->allow($_userRole, 'module-contr', array( $actions ));
```

it's not accepted as I want.

Comment: Those two arrays are identical. The only difference is that on the second the keys are assigned automatically by PHP.

Comment: i dont find any difference in both the arrays... :)

Comment: http://codepad.viper-7.com/8EHBsK

Comment: both are same, every array will have an index by default, which you cannot avoid. Coming to usage, you could use it as second array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those two arrays are essentially the same... The first array is simply how it will be displayed should you decide to print it out (with `print_r()` for example).  When you are defining an array IE. creating an array with values already inside it, you would write something like this -

```
$someArr = array(
  'index_of_another_array' => Array ( 'index' ,'edit' ,'add' ,'delete', 'search' )
);
```

Essentially the array you are creating already has the **numerical indexes implied by the order of their appearance**... The element at index `[0]` is the string `index`.  At index `[1]` you have the string `edit`... At index `[2]` you have `add`... and so on...

Another thing to note is this line that you stated -

```
$this->allow($_userRole, 'module-contr', array( $actions ));
```

With the last parameter, what you are essentially doing is passing the `$actions` **within** an additional array!  What you are doing is creating a new array with the first element equal to `$actions`.  I think you should remove that additional array by simply passing `$actions` and **not** `array( $actions )`

I hope this cleared things up a little bit...

Answer (score 0):

should be

```
$this->allow($_userRole, 'module-contr', $actions['visits-visit']);
```